# What is the formal criteria that the spacetime is curved?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, differential-geometry, curvature

We suppose we have three scenarios.

1. We are far away from mass and energy in a spot in the universe. We put in free movement a small object $m$, for example, an apple. At the same time, we send a light signal close to m and in the same direction as m. We will deduce that both trajectories will be straight lines in the Euclidean sense.
2. We do the same on earth from a certain height. While the trajectory of $m$ will be curved, the one by the light will not be for that long distance.
3. We repeat the same close to the surface of the Sun. Both trajectories will be curved.

When we speak about curved spacetime does the definition take into account only the behavior of light in terms of its trajectory? In other words, if we take into account only the trajectory of light and not $m$, can we claim that the space-time on Earth is Euclidean and thus the space-time on earth is not curved? In particular, the observation that a small object such as an apple thrown horizontally from a certain height on earth will have a curved trajectory, is it an argument for a curved space (or curved space-time) on Earth?

Comment: Spacetime on Earth is curved, and this has been demonstrated experimentally using light: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment

Comment: Thanks. In case we forget the light and consider only the trajectory of a small object such as an apple in free fall, is the evidence that it's trajectory is curved an argument about curved space?

Comment: "What is the formal criteria that the spacetime is curved?" $R_{abcd}\ne0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that a small object, (or even a beam of light) thrown horizontally, has a curved trajectory is not a proof for the space-time curvature.

The same behaviour happens inside a ship with a constant acceleration, and the crew are in a flat space-time.

A better experiment could be to let a bunch of small objects in free fall. The relative distances would keep the same in a flat space-time, but not in a curved one.

Answer (score 3):

In a straightforward sense, spacetime is curved if the Riemann curvature tensor does not vanish. This is as mathematically objective as it gets.

Conceptually, how can we measure this? As mentioned in another answer, one way is to let a bunch of objects fall freely. Notice you don't use a single object, but a collection of them.

The reason is that *locally* (i.e., at a single point) you can't distinguish gravitational effects from acceleration. This is often exemplified by the thought experiment in which you can't distinguish whether you are standing on a rocket that is at rest on the ground, or if you are standing on a rocket that is accelerating in space.

However, gravity and acceleration are different when you consider effects at more than one location. For example, drop a bunch of apples around the Earth: they will get closer as they fall because they are all falling toward the center of the Earth. You get tidal effects, which are a hallmark of gravitational effect. The same thing would hold for light.

> When we speak about curved spacetime does the definition take into account only the behavior of light in terms of its trajectory?

No. Spacetime curvature is a property of spacetime, not of the objects that move on it. It affects light, apples, oranges, and everything. While light does move in a slightly different way on spacetime (namely, on null geodesics, rather than on timelike geodesics), the properties of spacetime are the same for everyone.

> In other words, if we take into account only the trajectory of light and not $m$, can we claim that the space-time on Earth is Euclidean and thus the space-time on earth is not curved?

The Earth also bends the path of light. While the effects are more subtle (because spacetime is less curved than near the Sun), they are still there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Given that we do an experiment on the Earth and not in a accelerating space ship, I am still wondering why the curved trajectory of a falling body is not sufficient to consider the spacetime on Earth as curved? We may eventually consider many falling bodies at different hight or at same hight but different locations.

Comment: @user249018 A single falling body is not enough to distinguish whether it is falling due to spacetime curvature or because the Earth is accelerating upwards. More falling bodies (at same heights and different locations or at many different heights) will behave differently under spacetime curvature and under mere accelerated reference frames